# Get a non-contiguous active range by selection and use it programmatically Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I want to get a non-contiguous range by selection and use it programmatically.

If I select say, A1 to F10 so I have a Contiguous range I can use below and it will give `A1:F10`

```
function getSelectedRange_Contiguous(){
  var selected = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange(); // Gets the selected range
  var rangeString = selected.getA1Notation(); // converts it to the A1 type notation
  Logger.log(rangeString)
  return rangeString;
}
```

If I use the `macro recorder` and select `A1:A10` & `C1:C10` & `E1:E10` I get a function that will select a discontinuous range

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['A1:A10', 'C1:C10', 'E1:E10']).activate();
};
```

But how do you get a Non-Contiguous range from selection to be used programmatically

Non-Contiguous does not work, it gives `E1:E10`

```
function getSelectedRange_NonContiguous() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var selected = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRangeList([]);
  var rangeString = selected.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(rangeString)
  return rangeString;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

You need to use [getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverangelist) instead of `getActiveRange` to get the Non-Contiguous active range.

- Also it is better if you apply this method to a particular sheet instead of the spreadsheet object so you can later on be more specific on the sheet object.

### Solution:

```
function getSelectedRange_NonContiguous() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const selected = sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  // an array of selected ranges
  const notations = selected.map(rng=>rng.getA1Notation()); 
  // log them:
  notations.forEach(nt=>console.log(nt));
  return notations;
};
```

Keep in mind that if you are planning to use that function as a custom function (a custom formula in your sheet) you won't get live updates because of the custom formula restrictions.