# Is there a way to track nonadjacent ranges in Google Apps Script on an onEdit trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been through [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543200/get-a-non-contiguous-active-range-by-selection-and-use-it-programmatically-googl) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769121/how-are-non-adjacent-ranges-handled-by-the-onedit-simple-trigger-in-google-scr) [answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/110904/iterating-through-a-non-contiguous-range-in-google-spreadsheet), but none of the code is working as expected. I'm trying to track input into a specific range when there are edits to add points to a chart. When people paste into a range, the event only fires once.

The change I have been testing to track multiple inputs is the following:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
let selection = sheet.getActiveRangeList();
let ranges = selection.getRanges();

for (let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  console.log('Active ranges: ' + ranges[i].getA1Notation());
}
```

The console only shows the A1 notation for the first cell that was selected in the range. [I have seen the bug report from four years ago](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946), but I'm really hoping my implementation is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of functions with the method .getActiveRangeList()

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    sh.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach(rg => {
      Logger.log(rg.getA1Notation());
      rg.setBackground("yellow");
    });
  }
};

function getActiveRangeList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach(r => {
    Logger.log(r.getA1Notation());
  })
}
```

If I copy something into the clipboard and then make 3 non overlapping selections while holding down the control key and then hit control V it pastes in all three of the selected ranges but the Logger.log() only returns the first selected range from the onEdit() function.  However, if I run the other function immediately after that the Logger.log function returns the three A1Notations  for all three ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Though I can't seem to make my script behave the same way. I copied your code, changing the sheet name in the getActiveRangeList() function and removing the conditional in the onEdit() so that it runs regardless of the sheet.

The onEdit gives me the first A1 notation and highlights the first cell as a trigger. Then I run the getActiveRangeList as a separate file manually, giving me "A1" every time, even though A1 is not selected on the sheet I'm getting by name.